# Aurelia CLI project build error depending on environment

Tags: typescript, gulp, aurelia

I want to build my Aurelia CLI project, recently upgraded to v 1.0.2

when i build with command:

> au build -env prod

Everything builds smoothly, but when i use dev

> au build -env dev

I am met by an unintelligible stacktrace, finding an index error at module 'async-done'.

```
ERROR [Bundle] Failed to write the bundle
INFO [Bundle] Error: No element indexed by 0
C:\Users\401623\Documents\Repositories\TrackAndTrace\TrackTrace.Client\node_modules\async-done\index.js:18
    throw err;
    ^
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ([object Object])
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:171:17)
    at Gulp.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Object.error (C:\Users\401623\Documents\Repositories\TrackAndTrace\TrackTrace.Client\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\createExtensions.js:61:10)
    at handler (C:\Users\401623\Documents\Repositories\TrackAndTrace\TrackTrace.Client\node_modules\now-and-later\lib\mapSeries.js:43:14)
    at f (C:\Users\401623\Documents\Repositories\TrackAndTrace\TrackTrace.Client\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at f (C:\Users\401623\Documents\Repositories\TrackAndTrace\TrackTrace.Client\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\401623\Documents\Repositories\TrackAndTrace\TrackTrace.Client\node_modules\async-done\index.js:24:15)
    at done (C:\Users\401623\Documents\Repositories\TrackAndTrace\TrackTrace.Client\node_modules\async-done\index.js:40:12)
    at onError (C:\Users\401623\Documents\Repositories\TrackAndTrace\TrackTrace.Client\node_modules\async-done\index.js:51:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

What do you guys think?

Comment: I kinda fixed this, by commenting out sourceMaps from my Gulp src pipe in the transpile.js file in the Aurelia Project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all due to a faulty upgrade of the Aurelia CLI.

I npm installed the new version, but failed to replace the Aurelia Project properly.

If you follow Aurelia's own guide to upgrading, they ask you to create a new project with the command:

```
au new
```

And here it is of vital importance that you consider all the design choices of the project you wish to upgrade. My error was creating a default project, and thus not using the existing concepts and techniques.

After you have done that, you just delete your old Aurelia Project folder, and replace it with the new Aurelia Project, from the newly created project, you generated with the command 'au new'.